# Azure Elastic DB - Modify schema in each shard

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, ddl, azure-elastic-sharding

I'm new to the Elastic DB Feature from Azure and it looks really awesome.
But what i could not find is how you can update the schema of all shards. So if i have multiple Shards and i want to add/remove a Column, Table or just add/remove a Stored Procedure.

Well all Shards are Databases which i could access and modify one by one but is there no way to publish schema changes to multiple shards at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you don't mind playing with a preview, have a look at [SQL Database Elastic Jobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-jobs-powershell/) which would allow you to execute scripts across SQL Databases.

Answer (score 5):

it would be great if you can try Elastic Database jobs. I have just posted a PowerShell [example](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Managing-multiple-Azure-a17fa156) which provides the e2e experience of managing large numbers of Azure SQL Database databases at once.

The Elastic Database jobs feature (preview) enables you to reliably execute a Transact-SQL (T-SQL) script or apply a DACPAC across a group of databases including a custom-defined collection of databases, all databases in an Elastic Database pool (preview) or a shard set (created using Elastic Database client library.

For more information and documentation, see [Elastic Database jobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-jobs-powershell/).